# jquery change css of some of the children which have specific css, when you only know the parent

Tags: jquery, css

This is a very theorical question...

Let's say I have a known "ul", and in this "ul" there is a "li" whose background is not gray but white, I want to select this "li" and change its text... what would be the way to do this in jQuery?

I can find out the "li" with this:

```
$("ul#menu1").children().css("background-color", "white")
```

Now how do I write the command to make it change its text is:

```
.html("new text")
```

But how do I link these together? This is my problem... Thanks!

Comment: Caution - often calling jQuery methods with a single parameter ('background-color') will retrieve the value, but passing in a second will set the property to that value. In your case, you are actually setting the background to white, not checking it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your existing line of code:

```
$("ul#menu1").children().css("background-color", "white")
```

...does *not* find the particular li element that already has a white background, it selects all of the li elements and changes their background to white. If you want to select just the item(s) where the background is already white you can do something like this:

```
$("#menu1 li").filter(function() {
   return $(this).css("background-color") === "white";
}).html("new text");
```

Though you may find that `.css("background-color")` returns a string like `"rgb(255, 255, 255)"`, even if you *set* the color to the string `"white"`, in which case:

```
$("#menu1 li").filter(function() {
   var bc = $(this).css("background-color");
   if (bc) bc = bc.replace(/\s/g,"").toLowerCase();
   return bc === "white" || bc === "rgb(255,255,255)" || bc === "#fff" || bc === "#ffffff";
}).html("new text");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XfDy3/

Comment: Won't this change the background of ALL children to be white, then change the text?

Comment: @Katstevens - Yes it will. I just realised I'd misread the question because the OP presented a line of code and said that it would find the li element in question, when in fact it won't. Will update.

Comment: Nice one - was about to do the same. Over to you maestro ;-)

Comment: Thanks I did try to put these two together and the result was that all the children became white and all changed the text... hence my question ;)

Comment: @Katstevens - Thanks, but don't let me stop you posting an answer, yours might be better.